# Controller doesn't work properly

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, controller

I have a problem with controller in my spring mvc application.

I am getting all the entities from database and put them in the table in my jsp page.

I am adding an entity, the function works well, it adds an entity and refresh the page. But there is a problem when I try to refresh page...the same entity is added again, in general after adding an entity every refresh execute the post method again and finally i have many same entities.

This is the post method to add new entities:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminpanel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addNewSoftware(@ModelAttribute VersionInformation versionInformation) 
{

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("panel");

    persistanceDAO.insertVersionInformation(versionInformation);
    systemVersionsList.clear();
    systemVersionsList.addAll(persistanceDAO.getSystemVersions());
    model.addObject("systemVersionsList",systemVersionsList);
    model.addObject("versionInformation", new VersionInformation());

    return model;
}
```

This is my GET method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminpanel/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addNewSoftware(@ModelAttribute VersionInformation versionInformation) 
{

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("panel");

    persistanceDAO.insertVersionInformation(versionInformation);
    systemVersionsList.clear();
    systemVersionsList.addAll(persistanceDAO.getSystemVersions());
    model.addObject("systemVersionsList",systemVersionsList);
    model.addObject("versionInformation", new VersionInformation());

    return model;
}
```

Another problem is that when I am deleting an entity, the entity is deleted, but the site doesn't refresh. This is my post method responsible for deleting entity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminpanel/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView deleteSoft(@ModelAttribute(value="currentId") int currentId, @ModelAttribute VersionInformation versionInformation) 
{

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("panel");

    persistanceDAO.deleteSystemVersion(currentId);
    systemVersionsList.clear();
    systemVersionsList.addAll(persistanceDAO.getSystemVersions());
    model.addObject("systemVersionsList",systemVersionsList);
    model.addObject("versionInformation", new VersionInformation());


    return model;
}
```

Comment: Your get method is the same as your post method?  Looks like a copy & paste error.

Comment: Okey, i changed my post method to "/adminpanel/add". The browser goes to "adminpanel/add" and then when i refresh it's adding the same entity again. How can i force it to go to "/adminpanel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking at [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). If you are using Spring 3.1 and above, implementing this would be easy using [flash attribute](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/).

**Modification of your code with Post/Redirect/Get Pattern applied**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminpanel/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewSoftware(@ModelAttribute VersionInformation versionInformation, 
                                    final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("panel");

    persistanceDAO.insertVersionInformation(versionInformation);
    systemVersionsList.clear();
    systemVersionsList.addAll(persistanceDAO.getSystemVersions());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("systemVersionsList",systemVersionsList);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("versionInformation", new VersionInformation());

    return "redirect:/adminpanel/show-panel";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/adminpanel/show-panel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showSoftwarePanel(@ModelAttribute("systemVersionsList") List<YouDidNotShowTheTypeOFSystemVersionList> systemVersionsList,
                                    @ModelAttribute("versionInformation") VersionInformation versionInformation){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("panel");
    model.addObject("systemVersionsList", systemVersionsList);
    model.addObject("versionInformation", versionInformation);

    return model;
}
```

After doing that, your page is now safe from multiple form submit problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about using redirect after updating the data.

"Another reason to perform a redirect before displaying the result is to eliminate the possibility of the user submitting the form data multiple times. In this scenario, the browser will first send an initial POST; it will then receive a response to redirect to a different URL; and finally the browser will perform a subsequent GET for the URL named in the redirect response. " [quoted from Spring mvc doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

`GET` methods must only be used for [idempotent operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). For deletes and inserts you must use `POST`. [And after successful non-idempotent operation you must send a redirect to user](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html), so if he hits refresh no kittens harmed.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the problem is that when you refresh the page you are resending the data. If so you need to use the Redirect-after-POST pattern.

Try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminpanel/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addNewSoftware(@ModelAttribute VersionInformation versionInformation) 
{

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/panel");

    // move these lines
    persistanceDAO.insertVersionInformation(versionInformation);
    systemVersionsList.clear();
    systemVersionsList.addAll(persistanceDAO.getSystemVersions());
    model.addObject("systemVersionsList",systemVersionsList);
    model.addObject("versionInformation", new VersionInformation());
    // end

    return model;
```

}

**NOTE**: You should move the commented lines into a GET method otherwise, your version etc will appear in the URL after redirect